# starting spyder in different python environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder

I currently have spyder IDE installed in a py3.6 environment, and I would like to install it in a py2.6 environment. I have both environments set up, but I only have spyder installed in 3.6.

```
C:\Users\jberry>conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
py27                     C:\Users\jberry\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27
py36                     C:\Users\jberry\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36
root                  *  C:\Users\jberry\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3


C:\Users\jberry\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py27\Scripts>pip install spyder
Collecting spyder
  Downloading spyder-3.2.5-py2-none-any.whl (3.5MB)
    100% |################################| 3.5MB 1.2MB/s
Collecting qtpy>=1.2.0 (from spyder)
  Downloading QtPy-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psutil (from spyder)
  Downloading psutil-5.4.3-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl (223kB)
    100% |################################| 225kB 1.1MB/s
Collecting nbconvert (from spyder)
  Downloading nbconvert-5.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (387kB)
    100% |################################| 389kB 1.7MB/s
Collecting rope>=0.10.5 (from spyder)
  Downloading rope-0.10.7.tar.gz (244kB)
    100% |################################| 245kB 1.3MB/s
Collecting pyqt5 (from spyder)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from spyder) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5 (from spyder)
```

I researched and found how to find out that my spyder instance was only in my py36 folder, and not in py27. I tried `pip install spyder` but no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `pip` to install Spyder instead of `conda`? Why don't you simply use `conda` instead?

Comment: I tried conda, gave the same error. I was able to go into the anaconda navigator and go to my environment and download it from there. I'll respond with that answer

Comment: It can't give the same error, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this by going into the anaconda navigator and viewing the uninstalled packages. Creating a new environment, and using `conda install spyder` works, but dind't for this example.